# Lost executor 0 on 192.168.1.21: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I got this Error when i running random forest mllib on SUSY dataset.

> ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on 192.168.1.21: Remote RPC
>   client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds,
>   or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.

why?

Comment: I have a similar issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820940/databricks-job-timed-out-with-error-lost-executor-0-on-ip-remote-rpc-client

Were you able to figure out a solution