# Databricks Job timed out with error : Lost executor 0 on [IP]. Remote RPC client disassociated

Tags: apache-spark, driver, databricks, azure-databricks, executor

**Complete error : Databricks Job timed out with error : Lost executor 0 on [IP]. Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.**

We are running jobs using Jobs API 2.0 on Azure Databricks subscription and using the Pools interface for less spawn time and using the worker/driver as Standard_DS12_v2.

We have a job(JAR main) which has just one SQL procedure call. This call takes more than 1.2 hour to complete. After exactly 1 hour the worker node is getting terminated and the Job status becomes timed out. We thought this could be because the node was indeed idle in that 1 hour time span and hence added a sniffer thread which is continuously logging every 10 minutes. This has not resolved the issue. Please find the logs below :

```
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO StaticConf$: DB_HOME: /databricks
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: ========== driver starting up ==========
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: Java: Private Build 1.8.0_232
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: OS: Linux/amd64 4.15.0-1050-azure
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: CWD: /databricks/driver
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: Mem: Max: 17.5G loaded GCs: PS Scavenge, PS MarkSweep
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: Logging multibyte characters: ✓
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: 'publicFile' appender in root logger: class com.databricks.logging.RedactionRollingFileAppender
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: 'org.apache.log4j.Appender' appender in root logger: class com.codahale.metrics.log4j.InstrumentedAppender
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: 'null' appender in root logger: class com.databricks.logging.RequestTracker
20/01/16 10:49:43 INFO DriverDaemon$: == Modules:
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO DriverDaemon$: Starting prometheus metrics log export timer
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO DriverDaemon$: Universe Git Hash: 422793c171cb2855a8f424d226006093e5349873
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO DriverDaemon$: Spark Git Hash: 0c5791fc51d5c2b434155df16049c9f78e12e8fb
20/01/16 10:49:44 WARN RunHelpers$: Missing tag isolation client: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: TagDefinition(clientType,The client type for a request, used for isolating resources for the request.)
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO DatabricksILoop$: Creating throwaway interpreter
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: Customize spark config according to file /tmp/custom-spark.conf
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: new spark config: spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled -> true
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: new spark config: spark.network.timeout -> 4000
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: new spark config: spark.driver.host -> 10.30.2.205
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: new spark config: spark.executor.tempDirectory -> /local_disk0/tmp
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: new spark config: spark.databricks.secret.envVar.keys.toRedact -> 
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: new spark config: spark.driver.tempDirectory -> /local_disk0/tmp
20/01/16 10:49:44 INFO SparkConfUtils$: new spark config: spark.databricks.secret.sparkConf.keys.toRedact -> 


20/01/16 11:49:32 INFO DriverCorral$: Cleaning the wrapper ReplId-20fe8-56e17-17323-1 (currently in status Running(ReplId-20fe8-56e17-17323-1,ExecutionId(job-368-run-1-action-368),RunnableCommandId(6227870104230535817)))
20/01/16 11:49:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Asked to cancel job group 2377484361178493489_6227870104230535817_job-368-run-1-action-368
20/01/16 11:49:32 INFO ScalaDriverLocal: cancelled jobGroup:2377484361178493489_6227870104230535817_job-368-run-1-action-368 
20/01/16 11:49:32 INFO ScalaDriverWrapper: Stopping streams for commandId pattern: CommandIdPattern(2377484361178493489,None,Some(job-368-run-1-action-368)).
20/01/16 11:49:35 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on 10.30.2.208: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 0 (epoch 1)
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(0, 10.30.2.208, 41985, None)
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO DBCEventLoggingListener: Rolling event log; numTimesRolledOver = 1
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 0 successfully in removeExecutor
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200116104947-0000/0 is now LOST (worker lost)
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200116104947-0000/0 removed: worker lost
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 0 requested
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO DBCEventLoggingListener: Rolled active log file /databricks/driver/eventlogs/5656882020603523684/eventlog to /databricks/driver/eventlogs/5656882020603523684/eventlog-2020-01-16--11-00
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Master removed worker worker-20200116104954-10.30.2.208-38261: 10.30.2.208:38261 got disassociated
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO DBCEventLoggingListener: Logging events to eventlogs/5656882020603523684/eventlog
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Worker worker-20200116104954-10.30.2.208-38261 removed: 10.30.2.208:38261 got disassociated
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Handle removed worker worker-20200116104954-10.30.2.208-38261: 10.30.2.208:38261 got disassociated
20/01/16 11:49:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Shuffle files lost for worker worker-20200116104954-10.30.2.208-38261 on host 10.30.2.208
```

On the Cluster job page, we can see the event log as :

[image]

On the Job-run page, we can see the status as Timed Out,

[image]

As we can see in the logs:

1. The error happened exactly 1 hour after the job has started.
2. The job configuration is like below :

========================
**Edit 1**

This issue is reproducible and happening every time we run the simple jar file.

[image]

Comment: try reducing cache() in your code ,increase partitions .Basically try to find places where you are loading too much data in a single node or something like that.

Comment: Single jar file with a main method. Doing nothing. Absolutely nothing.  Just logging to log file every 5 minutes. Breaking after 5 minutes.

Comment: Had to pull out code to pin down this issue from a complicated application because the app was timing out. So this so called jar file is our test app only.

Comment: this error has no one fix. try breaking down your code and see where the error might be coming from line by line. you can try this... val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf);     
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR") , If the cause is logger.

Comment: Sorry, It was a very very silly thing we were doing in the API call. We were passing the timeout_seconds to 3600. Really embarrassing. Closing this issue now. thanks

Comment: @ankur Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Sure will do once i login

Answer (score 0):

Just to give the answer that has been provided in the comments:

Quoting from @ankur

> Sorry, It was a very very silly thing we were doing in the API call.
> We were passing the timeout_seconds to 3600. Really embarrassing